# launch powershell and commands at once

Tags: powershell

if I do this in a powershell:

```
echo beep ; echo beep
```

it prints:

```
beep
beep
```

but if I do this in a regular console:

```
powershell -command { echo beep ; echo beep }
```

it prints:

```
echo beep ; echo beep
```

what is the correct syntax to obtain the same result ?

Comment: powershell -command "&{echo beep ; echo beep}"

Comment: @SagePourpre That works, but note that there's no reason to use `& { ... }` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `...` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected - see [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2750).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a list of commands inside a *script block* (`{ ... }`) to `powershell -Command` for *execution as-is* is only supported *from within PowerShell itself*, as running `powershell -h` will tell you.

From *outside* of PowerShell, simply pass the commands as-is, but preferably inside double quotes, so as to prevent unintended up-front interpretation of the arguments by `cmd.exe`:

```
powershell -command "echo beep ; echo beep"
```

Note, however, that `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references (e.g., `%USER%`) are still expanded up front.

Alternatively, you could pass a script block (string)<sup>[1]</sup>
*preceded by `&`, the call operator* to ensure the script block's *execution*, but that is only necessary if you want to pass *arguments* to the script block:

```
powershell -command "& { echo $Args[0]; echo $Args[0] } beep"
```

`beep` is passed as the 1st argument, which the script block references as `$Args[0]`.

---

As an aside: In PowerShell `echo` is an alias of `Write-Output`, which writes to the success output stream; the output from any command or expression that isn't captured or redirected *implicitly* goes to the output stream, so that use of `echo` / `Write-Output` is generally unnecessary:

```
powershell -command "& { $Args[0]; $Args[0] } beep"
```

---

<sup>[1] From *inside* PowerShell, passing a script block to `powershell -command` causes the *calling* PowerShell session to recognize it and to treat the enclosed commands as the ones to *pass to the new session* to execute.

From *outside* of PowerShell, `{...}` is a *string* passed to the new session,
and it is the new session that then parses that string as PowerShell code. Evaluating a script block by itself, without explicit *invocation* via `&` (or `.`), simply outputs the literal contents of the script block, which explains your output; you can verify this behavior by submitting

`{ echo beep; echo beep }` at the PowerShell prompt.</sup>

Comment: It recognize passing script block to any native application, but not `powershell -command` only: `cmd /c echo -command { Test } -args Test`

Comment: @PetSerAl: Thanks; that is intriguing - and smells like a bug. Am I missing something? Is there a good reason for this behavior?

Comment: I do not know why it implemented this way. I can only speculate. Likely it is just better than other alternatives, like invent some complex buggy rule to decide when enable this transformation and when not. For example: `cmd /c powershell -command { Test }`. You can not just pass `ScriptBlock` to ordinary process anyway, nothing will broke if you always do that transformation.

Comment: Thanks, @PetSerAl. It's definitely an edge case and I get that detecting when PowerShell is the target executable is not always trivial, but note that you don't even need a preceding `-command` to trigger the current behavior: _any_ script block on the command line triggers the Base64-encoding behavior, whereas you could argue that when not invoking _PowerShell_, a script block should simply be _stringified_ (`.ToString()`) when passed to an external utility.